# Creating endpoint in cloud run with Terraform and Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run

I'm research for a way to use Terraform with GCP provider to create cloud run endpoint. For starter I'm creating testing data a simple hello world. I have resource cloud run service configured and cloud endpoints resource configured with cloud endpoints depends_on cloud run. However, I'm trying to pass in the cloud run url as a service name to the cloud endpoints. File are constructed with best practice, with module > cloud run and cloud endpoints resource. However, the Terraform interpolation for passing the output of 
 service_name = "${google_cloud_run_service.default.status[0].url}"
Terraform throughs an Error: Invalid character. I've also tried module.folder.output.url. 
I have the openapi_config.yml hardcoded in the TF config within
I'm wondering if it's possible to have to work. I research many post and some forum are outdated.

```
 #Cloud Run
 resource "google_cloud_run_service" "default" {
 name     = var.name
 location = var.location

 template {
   spec {
     containers {
       image = "gcr.io/cloudrun/hello"
     }
   }




   metadata {
     annotations = {
       "autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale" = "1000"
       "run.googleapis.com/cloudstorage"  = "project_name:us-central1:${google_storage_bucket.storage-run.name}"
       "run.googleapis.com/client-name"   = "terraform"
     }
   }
 }
 traffic {
   percent         = 100
   latest_revision = true
 }
 autogenerate_revision_name = true
}
output "url" {
 value = "${google_cloud_run_service.default.status[0].url}"
}

data "google_iam_policy" "noauth" {
 binding {
   role = "roles/run.invoker"
   members = [
     "allUsers",
   ]
 }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "noauth" {
 location = google_cloud_run_service.default.location
 project  = google_cloud_run_service.default.project
 service  = google_cloud_run_service.default.name

 policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.noauth.policy_data
}

#CLOUD STORAGE
resource "google_storage_bucket" "storage-run" {
 name          = var.name
 location      = var.location
 force_destroy = true

 bucket_policy_only = true


}


data "template_file" "openapi_spec" {
 template = file("${path.module}/openapi_spec.yml")
}

#CLOUD ENDPOINT SERVICE 
resource "google_endpoints_service" "api-service" {
 service_name   = "api_name.endpoints.project_name.cloud.goog"
 project        = var.project
 openapi_config    = data.template_file.openapi_spec.rendered
}
```

ERROR: googleapi: Error 400: Service name 'CLOUD_RUN_ESP_NAME' provided in the config files doesn't match the service name 'api_name.endpoints.project_name.cloud.goog' provided in the request., badRequest

So I later discovered, that the service name must match the same as the host/cloud run esp service url without https:// in order for the cloud endpoint services to provisioner. Terraform docs states otherwise in the form of " $apiname.endpoints.$projectid.cloud.goog " [terraform_cloud_endpoints](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/endpoints_service.html) and in GCP docs states that the cloud run ESP service must be the url without https:// > gateway-12345-uc.a.run.app
[Getting Started with Endpoints for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run)

Comment: You should first format your Terraform code with `terraform fmt` to make it readable. Then edit your question to update it. It would also be easier to help answer if you included the full error output that Terraform gives you rather than a truncated summary of it.

Comment: When I copied in the TerraForm config, the example was showing json along with TerraForm configuration so I manually edited into the box.
I had to hash through some errors and came down to only this error:400

Comment: I have this and will post the solution later