# Terraform passing output from parent module to child module with Google Cloud Platform provider

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Asking another question from my previous post found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62461956/creating-endpoint-in-cloud-run-with-terraform-and-google-cloud-platform)

In my development I have simplified CloudRun and CloudEndpoint from child module to root module as so >

-dir

- main.tf
- modules
- services

  - CloudRun
  - CloudEndpoints

I have main config provisioning CloudRun and CloudEndpoints modules. I'm able to create CloudRun  and CloudRun . Now the fun part, I've output the url and url minus prefix of api-gateway url  after provisioning the deployment. Then, I need to go into the CloudEndpoints > openapi_spec.yml to edit the host = api.gateway.url (without the https) and address to the CloudRun application url. I want to know how I can pass in the output from root dir (main.tf config) to child module as an variable for template_file?

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# GCP ENDPOINT service test 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


data "template_file" "openapi_spec" {
  template = file("${path.module}/openapi_spec.yml", { CloudRunESPURL2= module.CloudRunESP2.urlesp , CloudStorageURL2= module.helloapp.url })
}



resource "google_endpoints_service" "api-service" {
  service_name   = "api.endpoints.project.cloud.goog"
  project        = var.project
  openapi_config    = data.template_file.openapi_spec.rendered
  
 
}
```

**CloudRunESPURL2= module.CloudRunESP2.urlesp , CloudStorageURL2= module.helloapp.url**

The variables values that are passed in are the output of the variables being passed from child module to root module then back to child module.

I'm looking to simplify this step as one provisioned configuration.

Comment: I am not familiar with Terraform, although keep in mind that there are multiple [resources of support about Terraform](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform#terraform_support_for). As per the doc, "For questions about Terraform in general and common patterns, check the HashiCorp community portal.

Comment: I have solved this for the time and will post it later.
Thank you @tzovourn the the referral, this has pointed me to the next stage in my development.